# ionic sliding item changes to color of slider

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to change the background color of my item in this ion-item-sliding but when I do this the whole item changes to another color when i use one of the sliders.

```
<ion-list class="ion-padding">
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let reservation of reservations | async" class="ion-margin-vertical">
    <ion-item-options side="start" class="slide-right">
      <button class="slide-right" (click)="onDeleteReservation(reservation)"><a><em class="bx bx-trash icon-white"></em></a></button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <app-reservation [ngClass]="reservation.checkedIn ? 'checkedin' : null" [reservation]="reservation"></app-reservation>
    <ion-item-options side="end" class="slide-left">
      <button class="slide-left" (click)="presentModal(reservation)" ><a><em class="bx bx-wrench icon-white"></em></a></button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

```
.slide-left {
  background-color: #4E84F2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slide-right {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.checkedin {
  --ion-background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.1);
}
```

So when a reservation is checked in it should be green. but when i use the slider it changes to red or blue.
It doesn't happen when the reservation is not checked in and the background color is just default white

[this is how it looks without the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUtP.png)

[but this happens when i use the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rgPu.png)

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from codepen

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-item-sliding>
            <ion-item-options side="start">
              <ion-item-option color="danger" expandable="true">
                <ion-icon name="trash" size="large"></ion-icon>
              </ion-item-option>
            </ion-item-options>
            <ion-item lines="none">
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options side="end">
              <ion-item-option color="success" expandable="true">
                <ion-icon name="create" size="large"></ion-icon>
              </ion-item-option>
            </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
```